# Real-time multiplayer game using Cordova, Javascript, PHP, MySQL - Help & Tips

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, cordova

I'm trying to create a simple game (like Agar.io) in real time using Cordova: Javascript, AJAX, PHP & MySQL.

**The code works great:**

1) JS Send X and Y to PHP server

2) PHP saves X and Y to MySQL Database

3) PHP retrieves X and Y from MySQL Database

4) PHP posts X and Y

5) JS retrieves PHP post of X and Y

6) Display circle at retrieved X and Y coordinates

**Now for the problem..**

It's very slow! This whole process takes about 1 second to complete (giving it 1 second delay). Also, some times it even lags from 2-10 seconds!

I understand this method isn't the quickest, but I still feel like I may be doing something wrong or inefficient.

**HELP**

It may be that this is the most efficient way possible, but I feel I am doing something wrong. Or maybe there is a better method of doing this?

Also, I am currently using HostMonster, Shared account (Maybe that's the issue?), which I'm waiting for them to open so I can upgrade to a Dedicated server and try it on there.

**Note:** In the mean time, I'm really trying to avoid using Node.js / Websockets because servers are just very pricey. And the free ones are very limited =/

Worse comes to worse, I will learn more JS PHP MySQL :)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function update
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(test, positionX - c.width/40, positionY - c.width/40, c.width/20, c.width/20);

    if((directionX != positionX || directionY != positionY) &&
        dataServerSendOn && dataServerGetOn)
    {
        dataServerSendOn = false;
        dataServerGetOn = false;

        setTimeout(function(){requestAnimationFrame(sendData);}, FPS);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function sendData()
{
    var params = "uuid=" + uuid + "&directionX=" + directionX + "&directionY=" + directionY;

    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange =
    function()//Call a function when the state changes.
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            dataServerSendOn = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(getData);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}

function getData()
{
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
    function()
    {
        /*
         * 0: Hasn't Started
         * 1: Connected to the Server
         * 2: Server has received our request
         * 3: Server Processing
         * 4: Request is finished and data is ready
         */
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            httpTransferString = xmlhttp.responseText;
            requestAnimationFrame(sortData);
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/game", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function sortData()
{
    positionX = "";
    positionY = "";

    for(var i = 0; httpTransferString[i] != '&'; i++)
    {
        positionX += httpTransferString[i];
    }
    for(var i = positionX.length + 1; httpTransferString[i] != '#'; i++)
    {
        positionY += httpTransferString[i];
    }
    dataServerGetOn = true;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require 'core.php';
require 'connect.php';

if(loggedin())
{
    if(isset($_POST['uuid']) &&
       isset($_POST['directionX']) &&
       isset($_POST['directionY']))
    {
        $uuid       = $_POST["uuid"];
        $directionX = $_POST["directionX"];
        $directionY = $_POST["directionY"];

        $query = "SELECT `UUID` FROM `users` WHERE `UUID`='$uuid'";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {
            $queryX = "UPDATE `users` SET `x` = '$directionX'  WHERE `uuid`='$uuid'";
            $query_runX = mysql_query($queryX);
            $queryY = "UPDATE `users` SET `y` = '$directionY'  WHERE `uuid`='$uuid'";
            $query_runY = mysql_query($queryY);                 
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "You're not logged in";
}

?>
<form name="tcpForm" action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
UUID       <input type="text" name="uuid">      <br>
directionX <input type="text" name="directionX"><br>
directionY <input type="text" name="directionY"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

***Please any advice I will greatly appreciate, I am still a noob =]***

Comment: AJAX will kill a server (even a dedicated one) with only a handful of users. You really, REALLY need to look at one of the alternatives you've already listed (e.g. websockets)

Comment: The amount of money made proportional the amount spent on the servers seems very deranged :( And with no guarantee either. Is there maybe an alternative? What was used before node.js? :O

Comment: Firstly, are you using a persistent MySQL connection? If not, opening and then closing the connection on each request will be very expensive. Secondly, consider using a shared memory cache instead of the database and updating the database on shutdown if needed. It's less reliable but much faster than dealing with physical files. Now the problem you can't avoid unless you use websockets is that webservers (like apache) have their own overheads for each request.

Comment: @apokryfos Hi! Do you mean cookies? And what do you mean `overheads for each request`?

Comment: I mean [persistent database connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) and [memcached](https://memcached.org/). A webserver needs to do a lot of things from the time it receives a request, to the time it's ready to call the appropriate script that will handle the request, such as security checks, validity checks etc. You can avoid all that if you're implementing the listening socket by yourself.

Comment: Thank you apokryfos, I'm checking out memchached right now :)

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is not considered to be the best choice when it comes to real-time applications as it does not provide a full two-way communication. This means that whenever something changes on the server-side there will be no way to notify the client. The client would need to either to send a lot of requests, which puts a lot of load on the server or use `long-polling`. `Long-polling` is a way, actually more of a hack, to partially circumvent the lack of two-way communication in HTTP. It consists of the client sending a request to the server and the server keeping the connection open until there is something to respond back to the client. This is also not optimal as the server might run out of sockets.

Now for a good real-time service (or a game) you could use some of the protocols that are specifically targeted towards real-time. Enter `WebSockets` and `WebRTC`.

1. WebSockets are persistent duplex (two-way) connections between a server and a client which allow the client to send and receive much smaller "requests", basically only the app-specific data, to the server. Unlike HTTP this a persistent connection, which means that you don't need to send additional data with each request (headers for ex.). Another great thing is that WebSockets are supported in all major browsers and are currently becoming a de-facto standard for real-time comms.
2. WebRTC - this is a peer-to-peer connection protocol where you connect to other clients for communication and not directly to the server. This pretty much means that your players would connect directly to each other and this would be even faster as they would not be connecting to a centralized location, which could suffer from performance issues or network degradation. It is supported by most modern browser, with IE trailing behind.

So these are the best available options for creating real-time services/applications. I'd recommend using WebSockets as it is more mature and has a bigger adoption at the moment. If you have your mind set on using PHP you can checkout some of the ready-made libraries for working with websockets such as http://socketo.me/

Comment: Thank you Vasil, but these suggestions I've already researched and all link to node.js or some other external server (unless I'm wrong). I'm trying to make the most of my HostMonster website provider, trying to provide my website along with the servers in one location

Comment: I understand, however at first glance the Ratchet PHP library(http://socketo.me) seems like it might fit your hosting plan and it is not built on node.js, but on PHP. I'm sure someone else has come up with a php WebSockets library. Other than that I don't think you have great chance at a palpable performance increase.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a closer look on Ratchet :)